# Adding custom field and updating model problem in django

Tags: django, customization, models

I need to add a  colorpicker to my django model and wrote a custom widget. However when I add  this colordfield to my model, django gives this error:

```
column mediaplanner_ievent.color does not exist
LINE 1: ...nt"."bits", "mediaplanner_ievent"."capture_link", "mediaplan...
```

My model is :

```
from mediaplanner.custom_widgets import ColorPickerWidget

class ColorField(models.CharField):
        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
                kwargs['max_length'] = 10
                super(ColorField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def formfield(self, **kwargs):
                kwargs['widget'] = ColorPickerWidget
                return super(ColorField, self).formfield(**kwargs)


class iEvent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name= u"Uygulama Adı", max_length=100, unique=True)
    bits = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(verbose_name= u"Bitler",max_length=100)
    capture_link = models.URLField(verbose_name= u"Capture URL", null=True, blank=True)
    color = ColorField(blank=true) 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"red button"
        verbose_name_plural = u"red buttonlar"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_str( "%s"% self.name )
```

The strange thing is, when I looked my database, there exist  colorfield. I don't want to delete the db and load it again. But ofcourse if it's the only solution, then no choice ..

So someone can help me how to solve it?

Comment: your problem seems to be quite unclear to me, you are not using `colorfield` in your model definition! furthermore you are missing a field `color` in your db, not `colorfield`; you probably added this field after the table was created... Also pls name your classes accordingly to the django guidelines!

Comment: sorry for that, I updated the information

Answer (score 0):

The field in your database is named `colorfield` bu the field in your model is named `color`. You have to change one or the other to make it work again.